# Styling checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox, radio-button

I need to stylize some checkboxes through jquery, but I don't want to use plugins. I just need a simple jQuery code.

I thought to use a simple list with css style.

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="selected"><a id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
 <li><a id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
 <li><a id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the same time i put in the code the input checkboxes hidden by css:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="rivista_numero" value="1" checked />    
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="rivista_numero" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="rivista_numero" value="3" />
```

With jquery if I click to the " link the parent li element will receive the "selected" class and the checkbox with the same ID will be checked.

Do you think that this could be a good solution? Is it possible to achieve this result with jQuery?

Comment: No, it is not a good solution as not only should ID's be unique, but using numbers as ID's is also bad practice and will cause you problems.

Comment: I wouldn't use js to style checkboxes at all but use css: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4148544/1960455

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique. May be you can define them as class instead?

Comment: Can only one checkbox be checked at the time? I guess this is what you want - radiobutton would be better.

Comment: Elmo, no, I was wrong, I could select more than one checkbox. I've edited my question.

Comment: So, @JP-Hellemons answer is completely correct. No javascript needed - just CSS.

Answer (score 9):

No javascript required, just CSS 
http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/XvZY9/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" name="cc" />
<label for="c2"><span></span>Check Box 2</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    color:#000;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) -19px top no-repeat;
}
```

for radiobutton's 
http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/XvZY9/1/

source: http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/demo.html

Comment: I believe he wants `radiobutton` behavior rather and improperly chosen `checkbox`. 'With jquery if I click to the " link the parent li element will receive the "selected" class, the old li element with the same class loses it and the checkbox with the same ID will be checked.'

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo you are probably right, then Pennywise83 should use the radio part from the tutorial: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: @Pennywise83 has edited his requirements, so your first answer is fine.

Comment: Just want to point out setting `display: none` on the input will render tabbing through that part of the form useless. Better option would be `opacity: 0` and then set a `:focus` style

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin,

```
var checkboxHeight = "25";
var radioHeight = "25";
var selectWidth = "190";


/* No need to change anything after this */


document.write('<style type="text/css">input.styled { display: none; } select.styled { position: relative; width: ' + selectWidth + 'px; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); z-index: 5; } .disabled { opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); }</style>');

var Custom = {
    init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), span = Array(), textnode, option, active;
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if((inputs[a].type == "checkbox" || inputs[a].type == "radio") && inputs[a].className == "styled") {
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = inputs[a].type;

                if(inputs[a].checked == true) {
                    if(inputs[a].type == "checkbox") {
                        position = "0 -" + (checkboxHeight*2) + "px";
                        span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                    } else {
                        position = "0 -" + (radioHeight*2) + "px";
                        span[a].style.backgroundPosition = position;
                    }
                }
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                inputs[a].onchange = Custom.clear;
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    span[a].onmousedown = Custom.pushed;
                    span[a].onmouseup = Custom.check;
                } else {
                    span[a].className = span[a].className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
        for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
            if(inputs[a].className == "styled") {
                option = inputs[a].getElementsByTagName("option");
                active = option[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                textnode = document.createTextNode(active);
                for(b = 0; b < option.length; b++) {
                    if(option[b].selected == true) {
                        textnode = document.createTextNode(option[b].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                    }
                }
                span[a] = document.createElement("span");
                span[a].className = "select";
                span[a].id = "select" + inputs[a].name;
                span[a].appendChild(textnode);
                inputs[a].parentNode.insertBefore(span[a], inputs[a]);
                if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
                    inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
                } else {
                    inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
                }
            }
        }
        document.onmouseup = Custom.clear;
    },
    pushed: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*3 + "px";
        } else if(element.checked == true && element.type == "radio") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*3 + "px";
        } else if(element.checked != true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight + "px";
        } else {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight + "px";
        }
    },
    check: function() {
        element = this.nextSibling;
        if(element.checked == true && element.type == "checkbox") {
            this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            element.checked = false;
        } else {
            if(element.type == "checkbox") {
                this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } else {
                this.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
                group = this.nextSibling.name;
                inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for(a = 0; a < inputs.length; a++) {
                    if(inputs[a].name == group && inputs[a] != this.nextSibling) {
                        inputs[a].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
                    }
                }
            }
            element.checked = true;
        }
    },
    clear: function() {
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
            if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
            } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
                inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
            }
        }
    },
    choose: function() {
        option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
        for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
            if(option[d].selected == true) {
                document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
window.onload = Custom.init;
```

From http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Demo is here http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/example/

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
var setupCheckboxes = function() {
    // Checkbox Styling
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('checkbox');
        $('<span class="checkbox"></span>').insertAfter($this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $this.next('span.checkbox').addClass('on');
        };
        $this.fadeTo(0,0);
        $this.change(function(){
            $this.next('span.checkbox').toggleClass('on');
        });
    });
};
setupCheckboxes();
```

then in the css

```
.checkbox {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

span.checkbox {
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1px 0 0 -14px;
    top: 3px;
    float: left;
    &.on {
        background: $blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML checkboxes can't be stylized much so it's best to make your own ;)
I made one for myself and it uses no images just plain CSS. So, it is scalable and customizable.

To get the value of checkbox `$('#id_of_my_custom_checkbox').val()` -> true/false

Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/xr62yara/8/

HTML:

```
<div>

            <div id='mycheckbox' class='custom-checkbox'>
                <div class='custom-tick'></div>
            </div>

            <span>I agree</span>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-checkbox{
    border: solid 2px orange;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
  }
.custom-tick{
    border: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    cursor: inherit;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 8px;
    width: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 0px 0px 3px 4px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.custom-checkbox').click(function (e) {
        toggleCustomCheckbox(e.target);
    })
});

function toggleCustomCheckbox(el) {
    var tickEl = $(el).find('.custom-tick').addBack('.custom-tick');
    if (tickEl.css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'visible')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(true)
        alert('you ticked me')
    } else {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'hidden')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(false)
        alert('you un-ticked me')
    }

}
function setCustomCheckbox(checkboxid, val) {
    var tickEl = $(checkboxid).find('.custom-tick').addBack('.custom-tick');
    if (val && val === true) {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'visible')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(true)
    }
    else {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'hidden')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(false)
    }
}
```